# Show hidden fields when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

Hi I have multiple checkboxes of similar kind. I am applying javascript on the checkbox to show hidden fields. I have created a js code which works for a single checkbox, I want to apply a code that will work for all checkboxes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" id="box" style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical1" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" id="box" style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical2" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JS Code :-

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var box = document.getElementById('box');
checkbox.onclick = function() {
    console.log(this);
    if (this.checked) {
        box.style['display'] = 'block';
    } else {
        box.style['display'] = 'none';
    }
};
```

Now the thing is i can make individual javascript for all checkboxes but that will contain numerous js code, I want that a single javascript function can unhide the elements from every checkbox when clicked. A single js code should work for all checkboxes. Kindly please provide a way of doing it with plain javascript or jquery.

Comment: @yoo Can you please elaborate

Comment: **`id`** s must be unique. use **`class`** instead.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I know i can make id unique and create a second js for the second checkbox but I want that a single js code should cater to all checkboxes, is this possible?

Comment: @KartikeyVishwakarma You can use something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dzz44au8/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this 
on your check box's onchange event call function **onchange="showHiddenField(this)"**

and function is like

```
function showHiddenField(currentObject) {
    var inputDiv = $(currentObject).parent().next();
    if ($(currentObject).is(":checked")) {
        $(inputDiv).show().focus();
    }
    else {
        $(inputDiv).hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript `function` to make it.

```js
function toggleFields(boxId, checkboxId) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
  var box = document.getElementById(boxId);
  checkbox.onclick = function() {
    console.log(this);
    if (this.checked) {
      box.style['display'] = 'block';
    } else {
      box.style['display'] = 'none';
    }
  };
}
toggleFields('box1', 'checkbox1');
toggleFields('box2', 'checkbox2');
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <!--<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">-->
        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <!--<div class="col-md-4" id="box" style="display: none;">-->
      <div class="col-md-4" id="box1" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" name="practical1" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <!--<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">-->
        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <!--<div class="col-md-4" id="box" style="display: none;">-->
      <div class="col-md-4" id="box2" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" name="practical2" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is how this works, each checkbox will have the `id` of its `box` as a class, so that when ever that checkbox is clicked, we will use its class to make its `box` visible. This will work even if you have 1000 checkboxes

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("#check1, #check2");
for (i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].onclick = function() {

    if (this.checked) {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('class')).style['display'] = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('class')).style['display'] = 'none';
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="box">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4" id="box" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" name="practical1" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" class="box2">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4" id="box2" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" name="practical2" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. Solution in below code. i did this using JQuery.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  console.log(this);
 // $(this).parent().next().css('display','block');
  $(this).parent().next().toggle('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input name="chkbox" type="checkbox">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" data-box="box" style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical1" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input name="chkbox" type="checkbox">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" data-box="box" style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical2" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> First Please note down in your mind "id" is only apply on a single elemnt on each page for multiple element you can apply a "class"

`id="checkbox"` replace with `class="checkbox"`

> in Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".checkbox").change(function(){
   
  if($(this).prop("checked")){
   $(this).parents(".row").find(".box").show();
  }else{
   
     $(this).parents(".row").find(".box").hide();
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 box"  style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical1" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 box" style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical2" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why should the OP change his/her code to use Jquery? You can do this without using Jquery

Comment: yes but he also did the same thing using jquery and with sort code.i already mention that this ans in Jquery.

Comment: @TheFlash please read the line in question Kindly please provide a way of doing it with plain javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']")` to select all `checkbox` and iterate through the elements using `for` loop.

Note : The `id` should be unique for each element.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
for (i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].onclick = function() {

    if (this.checked) {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('class')).style['display'] = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('class')).style['display'] = 'none';
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="box">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4" id="box" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" name="practical1" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" class="box2">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4" id="box2" style="display: none;">
        <input type="number" name="practical2" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most narrowed (static) suggestion from your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $(this).parent().next().show();
        }else{
            $(this).parent().next().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Use class attribute to get dynamic process.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on google Chrome works.

gets id of input takes the number after "checkbox(gets_target)" string. creates a id with adding this number to end of "box"+number string

HTML :

```
<input onChange="display_hidden_field(this)" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
<div id="box2" style="display:none;">content</div>
```

Javascript :

```
function display_hidden_field(checkbox){
  var box_id = checkbox.id;
  var search_pattern = /checkbox(.*?)$/g;
  var number = search_pattern.exec(box_id);
  number = number[1];
  box_id = 'box'+number;
  var box = document.getElementById(box_id);
  if(checkbox.checked){
    box.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    box.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use code like this what i did in this your every checkbox id create like this "checkbox_1" and your box id like this box_1 and so on other numbers please check below code you will get idea what you need to do with your html and java script.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input id="checkbox_1" type="checkbox" onclick="myfunction(this);">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" id="box_1" style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical1" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>Practical Course:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox"  onclick="myfunction(this);">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" id="box_2" style="display: none;">
               <input type="number" name="practical2" class="form-control">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>


<script>
 function myfunction(obj)
 {
        var element_index = obj.id.split("_");
        console.log('box_'+element_index[1]);
        var box = document.getElementById('box_'+element_index[1]);
        if(obj.checked) {
         box.style['display'] = 'block';
        } else {
        box.style['display'] = 'none';
        }

 }
 </script>
```

Here in script i have given function name myfunction but you can set your function name as per your need. may this is helpful for you.